# Why is select on two channel much slower than 2x of the time to select on single channel?

Tags: go, channel

This benchmark with single channel only take `2.545 ns/op`:

```
func BenchmarkSingleSelect(b *testing.B) {
    ch := make(chan interface{}, 1)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ch:
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

But this benchmark with two channel takes `35.85 ns/op`:

```
func BenchmarkMultiSelect(b *testing.B) {
    ch := make(chan interface{}, 1)
    ch2 := make(chan interface{}, 1)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ch:
        case <-ch2:
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it non-linear?

Comment: Usually the difference between _one_ and _many_ is a big jump. Your first construct may involve optimizations that are only possible when a single channel is monitored. You'll see this if you add further benchmarks for 3 and 4 channels involved: benchmark time will roughly go linear, but having a single channel is special.

Comment: @icza  Are you sure it's caused by big jump? I was guessing it's the random selection that cause it to be slow, but in my benchmark there's no write, so there should be no need to randomly choose a ready one.

Comment: Please read my whole comment. If you add further benchmarks with 3 and 4 channels, benchmark time increases roughly linearly. Yes, not needing a random selection is one thing the one-channel case is special for.

Comment: @icza No, random selection has nothing to do here since none of the channels are ready, the raondom selection is related only when there're ready channels. And I know select 2,3,4,...n is linear, my question is specifically about select 1 and select 2, there must be something special happening otherwise the different should not be so big.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the difference between *one* and *multiple* is a big jump. Your first construct may involve optimizations that are only possible when only a single channel is monitored. You'll see this if you add further benchmarks for 3 and 4 channels involved: benchmark time will roughly go linear, but having a single channel is special.

This is really an implementation detail, for specifics, you must check / analyze Go's source code. One thing from the [Spec: Select statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.
>
> [...]

Channels of each `case`s are evaluated, and the result is a set of channels to receive from or send to. Since there is a `default` case, the compiler has to check if any of the communication ops are ready to proceed. In the general case when there are multiple channels involved, this requires a loop, and some data structure (e.g. a slice or a bitmap) that gathers the ready cases. In case of a single channel, the compiler may generate a more efficient code that doesn't involve a loop, and doesn't need a set to gather the ready cases, the generated code just has to check a single channel.

Comment: I don't think the set to gather the ready cases causes the difference here, since the set is always empty.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie It may be empty in your case, but the code has to prepare something because it may not be empty in all cases. There also has to be a loop to handle multiple channels.

Comment: Do you think an empty set and that loop will cause so much extra runtime cost? It should not if it's implemented correctly IMO.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie We're taking about 30 ns! Yes, I think that may make that much  (little) difference.

Comment: Here's some benchmark result: atomic add:7ns, atomic load:0.5ns, mutex.Lock+mutex.Unlock:13.6ns.  It's hard for me to believe that based on these numbers.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Channels are safe for concurrent use. The compiler has to generate code that coordinates for any potential concurrent code. Again, you need to check the source for specifics, but this may change from version-to-version, from platform-to-platform.